# Minimum supported rails version for postgres jsonb type?

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using rails 4.1.14. I have tried to add column with type jsonb. But says unknown type. Anyone know, what is the minimum rails version that supports jsonb data type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it was added here: https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/99b82fdf03fcf6d6ca8e2d810ba35011723a5267

It seems to have been added in version 4.2